# Populate a list with Modules and display it in a Dialogbox in DOORS

Tags: ibm-doors

I need a DXL script that fill a DialogBox with returned Module names'. I have several modules within a project.

Below is my current progress. My idea is to put all Module names in a List and then display the list in a DialogBox.

Can you help me write ´´´fillModulelist()´´´

```
// This DXL script iterates through all formal modules of the folder
DB      dbMain        = null
DBE     dbeModuleList   = null
DBE     dbeExport     = null
DBE     dbeExportPath = null

Folder  currFolder    = null

string startFolder="/Project/Folder";
int moduleCount=0;
 
void forAllModulesInFolder(Folder f)
{
  Item itemRef;
  string shType;
  string sItemNameFull;
  string sItemName;
  Module moduleReference;
 
  for itemRef in f do
  {
    shType = type(itemRef);
    print shType "\t";
 
    sItemNameFull = fullName(itemRef);
    print sItemNameFull "\t";
 
    sItemName = name(itemRef);
    print sItemName "\n";
 
  if(shType=="Folder")
  {
    string selectedFolder = sItemNameFull;
    Folder f = folder selectedFolder;
    forAllModulesInFolder(f);
  }
 
  if(shType=="Formal")
  {
    moduleReference = read(sItemNameFull,false,true);
    filtering off;
    // do s.th. with the moduleReference
    close(moduleReference);
    moduleCount++;
  }
}}

void fillModuleList()
{
    //........... HELP NEEDED........
    
}
 
// Main-Method
void main(void)
{
  string selectedFolder = startFolder;
  Folder f = folder selectedFolder;
  forAllModulesInFolder(f);
  print "Affected Modules: " moduleCount "\n";
}
 
main();
```

Any help provided I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the list of modules is for displaying it to the user (and perhaps let them select from that list), it is best to display the full name of the modules, thus I would not store the module reference. You can open the module later, when the user has selected/double clicked the module (supposing that this is what you want). Thus, I fill a Skip list with `sItemNameFull, sItemNameFull`, but if it suits your script better, you can also fill it with `moduleReference, sItemNameFull` (use `create` instead of `createString` in this case). The changes to your script are marked with `//->>` and `//<<-`

```
// This DXL script iterates through all formal modules of the folder
DB      dbMain        = null
DBE     dbeModuleList   = null
DBE     dbeExport     = null
DBE     dbeExportPath = null

Folder  currFolder    = null

string startFolder="/testtrunk";
int moduleCount=0;

//->>
Skip skModules = createString()
//<<-
 
void forAllModulesInFolder(Folder f)
{
  Item itemRef;
  string shType;
  string sItemNameFull;
  string sItemName;
  Module moduleReference;
 
  for itemRef in f do
  {
    shType = type(itemRef);
    print shType "\t";
 
    sItemNameFull = fullName(itemRef);
    print sItemNameFull "\t";
 
    sItemName = name(itemRef);
    print sItemName "\n";
 
  if(shType=="Folder")
  {
    string selectedFolder = sItemNameFull;
    Folder f = folder selectedFolder;
    forAllModulesInFolder(f);
  }
 
  if(shType=="Formal")
  {
    //->>
    put (skModules, sItemNameFull, sItemNameFull)
    //moduleReference = read(sItemNameFull,false,true);
    //filtering off;
    // do s.th. with the moduleReference
    //close(moduleReference);
    //<<-
    moduleCount++;
  }
}}

//->>
void fillModuleList(Skip skContent, DBE dbeList)
{
    empty dbeList
    int cnt=0
    string sLine
    for sLine in skContent do {
        insert (dbeList, cnt, sLine)
        cnt++
    }
}
//<<-


//->>
void DoSomethingWithDoubleClickedModule (DBE x) {
    string sModName = get(x)
    print "doing something with " sModName "<---\n"
}


void canvasDummyCB( DBE dummy ) { }
void doNothing(DBE x) {}
void prepareGui()
{
    const string sArEmpty[] = {}

    dbMain = create ("mytitle", styleCentered)
    
    DBE spaceLeft = canvas(dbMain, 0, 0, canvasDummyCB)
    spaceLeft->"top"->"form"; spaceLeft->"left"->"form"
    spaceLeft->"right"->"unattached"; spaceLeft->"bottom"->"unattached"
    
    DBE spaceRight = canvas(dbMain, 0, 0, canvasDummyCB)
    spaceRight->"top"->"form"; spaceRight->"right"->"form"
    spaceRight->"left"->"unattached"; spaceRight->"bottom"->"unattached"
    
    DBE dInfoTextLabel = label(dbMain, "choose a module")
    dInfoTextLabel->"top"->"form"
    dInfoTextLabel->"left"->"flush"->spaceLeft
    dInfoTextLabel->"right"->"flush"->spaceRight
    
    dbeModuleList = list( dbMain, "Modules", 200, 15, sArEmpty)  
    dbeModuleList->"top"->"flush"->dInfoTextLabel
    dbeModuleList->"left"->"flush"->spaceLeft
    dbeModuleList->"right"->"flush"->spaceRight

    realize dbMain

    set( dbeModuleList, doNothing, DoSomethingWithDoubleClickedModule)

}
//<<-


// Main-Method
void main(void)
{
  //->>
  prepareGui()
  //<<-
  
  string selectedFolder = startFolder;
  Folder f = folder selectedFolder;
  setempty(skModules)
  forAllModulesInFolder(f);
  //->>
  fillModuleList (skModules, dbeModuleList)
  //<<-
  print "Affected Modules: " moduleCount "\n";
}
 
main();
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike. I find your answer very helpful, and make sense for the next step for my implementation. My end goal is export the selected modules to excel, do you have any idea how can I proceed based on your answer?

Comment: in what direction do you need help? The next step would be to fill the function DoSomethingWithDoubleClickedModule (which should be renamed of course). In this, you get the full name of the module to be exported (`sModName`). In this function you will read the module and do the export.

For the export itself, there are several possibilities. The hard way is to use OLE Automation to communicate with Excel (perhaps you should use the code of the "Enhanced Export to Excel" of Galactic Solutions Group, http://www.galactic-solutions.com/downloads/GalacticDownloadExcel.htm).

Comment: an easier way is to create a csv or tsv file, with a heading line, using <CRLF> as line separator, comma, semicolon or tab as field separator and surrounding the values with quotation marks. The built-in excel exporter should help you here for a start. Look at DOORS HOME\lib\dxl\standard\export\office

Comment: Thank you again for your valuable input. I find the solution provided by Galactic Solutions Group pretty nice and well structured, I appreciate you sharing this here. However, my goal is to export multiple modules at once after I select them. In a single folder I have over 50 modules and to do this manually takes a lot of time and efforts. I hope you that you understand my point. Do you think is it possible to combine my script with the one you provided will work ? In overall thank you for your inputs so far they have been very helpful.

Comment: Well, sure they can be combined. The code you have up to now is the part that controls what is done.  "Enhanced Export to Excel.dxl"  contains the code to export the module. I would say, you will have to work over "Enhanced Export to Excel.dxl" , deleting all the GUI stuff and use your own GUI stuff. I think you will have to call excelPerformExportForModule, but you should better look yourself, I did not have the time to look into details.

Comment: about your own gui stuff, it depends on what you want your user to do. Shall they do nothing, is the list only for displaying which modules have been exported? In this case, you might want to call the export where you originally had the line "do something with the moduleReference" and use the list only to show results. 
Shall the user be able to choose which modules to export? In this case, you should perhaps use a `listView` DBE instead of `list` and give it the `listViewOptionCheckboxes` style. Make a `button` for export and iterate over all checked modules.

Comment: Thank you for your time. In the GUI I want to show the available modules within a folder, and then the user selects the modules he wants to export and then exports all of them at once with one click. The problem here is the configuration will apply to all modules or the user have to configure the tool before exporting every module. The ultimate goal is automate the export of multiple modules, it doesn't matter if the modules are in a single Excel I mean every module in a sheet or every module in a different excel. What do you think?

Comment: what do you mean by "configuration"? The check boxes like "Add Cell Borders to Export Area" et al.,? Well, of course, you will either have to find default parameters which are valid for each and every module to be exported or you will have to invent some kind of mapping mechanism that stores and remembers the perfect settings for each module, otherwise the user will have to do many clicks. From what I read from the dxl file, you will ultimately have to call  `excelPerformExportForModule` and give the correct parameters, like `bool   XLdoExportTableCells` for "Add Cell Borders..."